# Lucene - Always necessary to provide Fields?

Tags: lucene, indexing, field

I was wondering if it is always necessary to provide fielded data to lucene before it can index the data? Or are there any options where non fielded data can be pushed to the index.
Supposing I have a text file that contains text that has no fielded information and this needs to be indexed.

Thanks

Wajih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene behaves much like a traditional database, you need to define a *schema*. You can't put a text file into a database without specifying into which column in which table the text should go. In the same vein, you can just make a schema that contains a single field like `text` and put all your text file contents into that.